# MYSQL LEFT JOIN only returns one row from joined table

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following SQL query and I am only returning one unit per site, there should be 10-20 units per site:

```
SELECT site.*, units.*
FROM site
LEFT JOIN units
    ON site.id=units.id
WHERE site.submitted='1' AND unit.color ='Green'
ORDER BY site.time DESC
LIMIT 0,100;
```

Comment: If there's 10-20 units per site, and you want only one per site, which one do you want? Also, is it correct that you're joining on `site.id = units.id`? Do you not have a `units.site_id` foreign key?

Comment: Show us the table data. It would help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `WHERE` clause is prematurely filtering off records which you expect to appear in your result set.  Try moving the `WHERE` logic into the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT s.*, u.*
FROM site s
LEFT JOIN units u
    ON s.id = u.id AND
       u.color = 'Green'
WHERE s.submitted = 1
ORDER BY s.time DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

I introduced aliases into the query (i.e. `u` for `units` and `s` for `site`), which help make it easier to read.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the benefit of putting the `s.submitted = 1` condition in the `ON` clause?

Comment: @fubar You're right, there isn't any.  But moving the color check to the `ON` clause might help.